# Google People API: Why are birthdays returned in an array format

Tags: oauth, google-signin, google-authentication, google-people-api

Any given google account should have 1 birthday.
When using the people API, to retrieve the birthday of the user, I was surprised to find that the retrieved birthday response is inconsistent.
I.e: The response retrieved for two different accounts is not structurally the same.

I noticed this:

**Birthdays can be an array of 2 or 1 birthdays.

I noticed if it's 2 birthdays The second value in the array contains the year.

While the first one contains only month and day for some reason.

[image]

If it's 1 birthday Then it contains the year, month, day.**
[image]

```
const validateGoogleAccessTokenAndReturnPersonalInfo = async (
  tokenId,
  accessToken
) => {
  try {
    const CLIENT_ID =
      "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: tokenId,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,
    });

    const payload = ticket.getPayload();

    const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken });

    const peopleAPI = google.people({
      version: "v1",
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });

    const { data } = await peopleAPI.people.get({
      resourceName: "people/me",
      personFields: "birthdays",
    });

    const {birthdays} = data;
    let  birthday

   

    if (birthdays) {
      /**Birthday
      A person's birthday. At least one of the date and text fields are specified. The date and text fields typically represent the same date, but are not guaranteed to.
      #TODO: What if text is there.
      */

      // #NOTE:
      // biryhdays can be an array of 2 or 1 birthdays
      // I noticed if it's 2 birthdays
      // The second value in the array contains the year
      // While the first one contains only month and day for some reason
      // If it's 1 birthday
      // Then it contains year,month,day
      // For this reason I'll be using birthdays.length - 1
      // I am not sure this is applicable to all accounts though
      // So I need to verify it

      const { year, month, day } = birthdays[birthdays.length - 1].date;
      birthday = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }

   

    const response = {
      birthday: birthday,
    };
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    throw new Error("Google token validation failed");
  }
};
```

So I had to make a trick to verify that I successfully get the birthday of the user:

> For this reason I'll be using birthdays.length - 1 I am not sure this
> is applicable to all accounts though So I need to verify it

Here:

```
const { year, month, day } = birthdays[birthdays.length - 1].date;
```

The problem with this approach is that I am not sure it will work for all accounts.

Comment: This is not something that we can answer recommend you post it to the issue forum https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:344199%2B

Comment: Adding to what @DalmTo you should maybe add more detail about the users. Maybe one is imported and the other is not, or you have added in a different way. There should be something that makes the contacts different from each other and that should be known before [creatin the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=344199&template=1041029).